# C# Custom Scrolling Cartesian graph

Tags: c#, arrays, graph, scroll, gdi+

I would like to ask for some insight/guidance on the following issue:

I am creating a custom scrolling graph in C#. I DEFINITELY not wanting to use the graph control in Visual Studio. Period. I want this completely original code.

**A little background:**

I have a function that returns a float value representing a signal amplitude.

I sample these values at an arbitrary interval set at runtime by the user.

I place these values into an Array of `PointF`.

A new value is pushed into the bottom of the array and the top value is removed. Thereby creating a buffer.

The length of the array is determined by the width of the "plot".

As the "plot rectangle decreases in width, the array is resized and leading values are dropped, as the "plot" is widened the array is resized and the missing values are added to the top of the array as "zeroed" points (as in the 0 points on my Cartesian graph).

I draw these points onto the plot and this produces a trace on the graph.
Each time a value is entered into the bottom of the array, I repaint the entire "plot" rectangle area and the result is a moving graph that represents the signal as a function of time.

Now, there is no minimum and maximum values preset for the signal power. If I set an upper or lower bound, then any signal level outside of the bounds of the graph will not show (it will clip).

To remedy this, I calculate the scale of the "plot" on the x-axis and scale the Points in the array to the same factor. I do this by finding the max and min values for upper and lower in the array and use those values to auto-scale the graph.

This all works great - sort of. It's usually fast to render, but sometimes my values still go outside of bounds (I know why this is happening and will fix it later). It also uses more code than I would like.

Here is an image graph so far:

[image: image graph]

Would it be neater and cleaner / easier to draw the trace on a graphics path directly (instead of using a buffer) in 1:1 scaling, then somehow clip the region I am interested in, render it, add a new value, draw the new line from the newest point I added, clip it, render it, repeat?

Instead of calculating scale, I could just use a matrix to transform the clip to the proper size for my "plot"?

Thereby my "plot" rectangle would actually be a window I could move horizontally along the plot of the entire value and I could zoom in / or zoom out in time (y-axis) and signal level (x-axis) by using a matrix to transform the scale and offset?

I have never used the graphics path or matrix before in GDI+ and have always manually drawn everything by using a double buffer, overriding the `OnPaint()` method and the `OnPaintBackGround()` method and drawing my objects from there.

Any help would be appreciated.  If you need the code I can provide it here as well.

Comment: _the graph control in Visual Studio_ Huh? What would that even be??